# Will this autoprogram circuit work with an ESP32-WROOM-2?

Tags: design, esp32, ftdi

I am replacing another design that used an ESP32-WROWER-B with an ESP32-S3-WROOM-2.
I connected the autoprogram circuit similar to what it was on the WROWER but I am not sure if it will work and I don't have the WROOM to test with. Could someone verify it this will work? I am using an FTDI adapter to program the WROWER and wish to use it again on the S3.

[image]

- [ESP32-WROOM-2](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-wroom-2_datasheet_en.pdf)
- [ESP32-WROWER-B](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wrover-b_datasheet_en.pdf)
- [FTDI](https://www.amazon.in/Geekcreit-FT232RL-Converter-Adapter-Arduino/dp/B07769YC9R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this using an ESP32-WROOM-1 and it worked as expected(flashing new firmware without the need for any user intervention). Since the programming/flashing procedure is the same for ESP32-S3 series modules I can assume that this will work on the ES32-WROOM-2 as well.

ESP32-S3 series technical ref: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf